# Unable to stage app: 'posix:permissions' not supported as initial attribute - when run appengineDeploy

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

This error apears on appengineStage cmd, only **if project has** *.**jsp** files. If I delete it cmd execute without error.

Why?

Ran into a bug today after update on GCloud 437:

**Env:**

- Windows 11
- Idea Community with Gradle (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/app-gradle-plugin)
- Google Cloud SDK 437.0.0
- app-engine-java 2.0.15
- app-engine-python 1.9.105
- bq 2.0.93
- cloud-datastore-emulator 2.3.0
- core 2023.06.26
- gcloud-crc32c 1.0.0
- gsutil 5.24

**Error:**
18:41:13: Executing 'appengineDeploy'...

Beginning interaction for module default...
0% Scanning for jsp files.
0% Compiling jsp files.

**Unable to stage app: 'posix:permissions' not supported as initial attribute
Please see the logs [C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg3398356686094508289.log] for further information.**

-> Task :appengineStage
-> Task :appengineStage FAILED
6 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 4 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':appengineStage'.
  -> com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.AppEngineException: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.operations.cloudsdk.process.ProcessHandlerException: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.AppEngineException: Non zero exit: 1
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 35s
18:41:50: Execution finished 'appengineDeploy'.

**In file appcfg3398356686094508289.log:**

**Unable to stage:
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: 'posix:permissions' not supported as initial attribute
at** java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsSecurityDescriptor.fromAttribute(WindowsSecurityDescriptor.java:358)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:497)
at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:690)
at java.base/java.nio.file.TempFileHelper.create(TempFileHelper.java:135)
at java.base/java.nio.file.TempFileHelper.createTempDirectory(TempFileHelper.java:172)
at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.createTempDirectory(Files.java:966)
at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.io.TempFileCreator$JavaNioCreator.createTempDir(TempFileCreator.java:102)
at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.io.Files.createTempDir(Files.java:439)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.compileJsps(Application.java:1229)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.populateStagingDirectory(Application.java:994)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.createStagingDirectory(Application.java:877)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.stageApplication(AppAdminImpl.java:76)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.stageApplicationWithDefaultResourceLimits(AppAdminImpl.java:44)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg$StagingAction.execute(AppCfg.java:921)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.executeAction(AppCfg.java:289)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.(AppCfg.java:148)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.(AppCfg.java:88)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.main(AppCfg.java:83)
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AdminException: Unable to stage app: 'posix:permissions' not supported as initial attribute
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.stageApplication(AppAdminImpl.java:82)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.stageApplicationWithDefaultResourceLimits(AppAdminImpl.java:44)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg$StagingAction.execute(AppCfg.java:921)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.executeAction(AppCfg.java:289)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.(AppCfg.java:148)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.(AppCfg.java:88)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.main(AppCfg.java:83)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: 'posix:permissions' not supported as initial attribute
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsSecurityDescriptor.fromAttribute(WindowsSecurityDescriptor.java:358)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:497)
at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:690)
at java.base/java.nio.file.TempFileHelper.create(TempFileHelper.java:135)
at java.base/java.nio.file.TempFileHelper.createTempDirectory(TempFileHelper.java:172)
at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.createTempDirectory(Files.java:966)
at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.io.TempFileCreator$JavaNioCreator.createTempDir(TempFileCreator.java:102)
at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.io.Files.createTempDir(Files.java:439)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.compileJsps(Application.java:1229)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.populateStagingDirectory(Application.java:994)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.createStagingDirectory(Application.java:877)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.stageApplication(AppAdminImpl.java:76)
... 6 more

**this error get only if I run appengineDeploy.
appengineEun and explodeWar localy work without error**

Comment: This error apears on appengineStage cmd, only if project has *.jsp files. If I delete it cmd execute without error.
Unable to stage: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: 'posix:permissions' not supported as initial attribute

Answer (score 1):

**Theres a problem with the update.**

[GitHub issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-java-standard/issues/25)

They recommend go back a previous version

Answer (score 0):

see GoogleCloudPlatform post for [workaround](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/app-gradle-plugin/issues/458)

Answer (score 0):

I've updated the components and it works.

gcloud components update